# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException, Numerous errors

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm pretty new at when it comes to Java and I am having an issue with this new Program that I am designing. I believe it might have something to do with the Scanner, but I am not so sure. I apologize if my formatting is off, this is my first post. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package commissioncalculationprogram;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculate {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // for user input

        //create new object to compute compensation and  find the highest earner
        Salesman a = new Salesman ();

        System.out.print("How many salespersons do you want to compare: ");
        int SIZE = input.nextInt(); //**** Line 14 in original code ****

        String[] name = new String[SIZE];
        double[] sale = new double[SIZE];
        double[] compensation = new double[SIZE];

        // input data for each person and compute compensation for that one
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter name of person " + (i+1) + ": ");
            name[i] = input.nextLine();           
            System.out.print("Please enter total annual sales of person " + (i+1) + ": $");
            sale[i] = input.nextDouble();
            compensation[i] = a.calculation(sale[i]);
        }

        // find index of the highest earner in array
        int highest = a.highest_earner(compensation, SIZE);

        // display the highest earner
        System.out.println("\nThe highest earner is: \n" + name[highest] + 
                       " with total sales: $" + sale[highest] +
                       " and total compensation: $" + compensation[highest]);

        // calculate and display the additional amount of sales that each salesperson 
        // must achieve to match or exceed the higher of the two earners
        System.out.println("\nAdditional amount of sales needed for others to match the higgest earners:");
        System.out.format("%-25s%10s\n", "   Name", "Sale amount needed");

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            if (i == highest) {
                continue;
            } // skip the highest earner

            //System.out.println(name[i] + "\t\t$" + (sale[highest] - sale[i]));
            System.out.format("%-25s%10s\n", name[i], (sale[highest] - sale[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the code, I get these errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at commissioncalculationprogram.calculate.main(calculate.java:14)
```

Using the suggestions provided.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); // for user input
    //create new object to compute compensation and  find the highest earner
    salescalc a = new salescalc ();
    // ask user enter number of salespersons
    int size = 0;
    System.out.print("How many salespersons do you want to compare: ");
    if(s.hasNextInt())
    {
    size = s.nextInt();
    }
    s.close();

     New errors

     commcalculator/commcalculator.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        input.nextLine();
        ^
      symbol:   variable input
    location: class commcalculator
    commcalculator/commcalculator.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        name[i] = input.nextLine();           
                  ^
    symbol:   variable input
    location: class commcalculator
    commcalculator/commcalculator.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        sale[i] = input.nextDouble();
                  ^
    symbol:   variable input
    location: class commcalculator
    3 errors
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what code is at line 14 in your `calculate.java` file?

Comment: Note that this is not a compilation error but an exception at runtime

Comment: I think you're closing the Scanner somewhere in your code, and then you are attempting to read from the closed stream

Comment: @Andrew int SIZE = input.nextInt(); is what I have at line 14

Comment: @Mati Cicero  I believe so too, but I am having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: @Dwill34 you should check if the scanner has an int before grabbing it.  Use input.hasNextInt() to check.

Comment: @Zoop Where should I place input.hasNextInt() in the code?

Comment: int SIZE;

if (input.hasNextInt()) { SIZE = input.nextInt(); }

Comment: You mean, when you try to **run** the code.

Comment: @Dwill34 Laambi's answer is good but you should probably initiate SIZE outside of the if statement and then check if size was set before using it.

Comment: Ups. I agree. Initialize size outside. And use lowercase if it's not a constant.

Comment: Is hasNextInt() needed if he does input an int? I mean, will he get this error if he inputs an int or just a non-int? Or is the check just needed if the input is not an int?

Comment: @Zoop I tried using int SIZE; if (input.hasNextInt()) { SIZE = input.nextInt(); } in place of  int SIZE = input.nextInt(); but I continued to get errors.

Comment: Did you get the same errors, or new ones?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the hasNextXXXX() methods from the Scanner class to make sure that there is an integer ready to be read.

The problem is you are called nextInt() which reads the next integer from the stream that the Scanner object points to, if there is no integer there to read (i.e. if the input is exhausted then you will see that NoSuchElementException)

From the JavaDocs, the nextInt() method will throw these exceptions under these conditions:

InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
You can fix this easily using the hasNextInt() method:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size= 0;

 System.out.print("How many salespersons do you want to compare: ");
    if(s.hasNextInt()) 
    {
       size= s.nextInt();
    }

    s.close();
```

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary with `System.in`.

Comment: @Mayank I tried using what you suggested, but I received a lot more errors. Where exactly would you place that in the code that I developed?

Comment: @Dwill34 I have edited the code.You need to put this piece where you are trying to read it. If you are still getting errors, can you please post the code and the errors.

Comment: `code`commcalculator/commcalculator.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
            input.nextLine();
            ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class commcalculator
commcalculator/commcalculator.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
            name[i] = input.nextLine();           
                      ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class commcalculator
commcalculator/commcalculator.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
            sale[i] = input.nextDouble();
                      ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class commcalculator
3 errors `code`

Comment: @MayankAgarwal Sorry for the formatting, but that is what I get with the changes

Comment: @Dwill34: You have to do it the same way for all the places where you have used input.nextLine or input.nextDouble. Put a similar if statement foe all those cases.

Answer (score 0):

#### input.nextInt() or input.nextDouble() etc...

Scanner throws: NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted.

Are you sure input has more elements?

I would refactor  the code as:

if(input!=null && input.hasNext()){
..
..
}

AND

if(input!=null && input.hasNextLine()){
..
..
}

Comment: This is `System.in`. It should wait if there's no input I think. In fact, the first example in the Javadoc does it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with your scanner.

The scanner input method uses a buffer to capture and store the data entered.

Nextline will capture all data to the end of the return character, which, empties the buffer.

All the other scanner methods such as Nextint, capture data from the buffer till before the return character, which basically ends your next scanner capture prematurely, due to the remaining return character.

Try and add a input.nextline(); after you capture your input from any scanner methods to clear the buffer and prevent issues with with the scanner input methods.

That's how I understand it, if someone has a better explanation I would be all ears.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're running the app in a way that doesn't bind it to the console, and therefore `System.in` is just reading EOF. For example, you're running it through a (dumber) IDE or you're using an older version of Maven to execute it. Try running directly from the console (your command prompt) and see if it works.

If this was an IDE issue, let us know which one it was so it can be shamed.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 8.0 and I am able to run the program fine from there; however, I am getting exception errors.

Comment: @Dwill34: Try running directly from your command prompt/terminal. Not from within Netbeans.

Comment: @Dwill34: Also, what OS are you running on, and from the console, when you run `java -version` what does it say?

Comment: @Dwill34: You also have some unrelated style issues that are serious enough that you'll lose points for them. `SIZE` is not a constant, so it should not be capitalized. `Salesman` appears to be acting as a a utility class instead of holding data for each individual salesperson, which is most likely what was intended.